# How do I access video views/analytics on a video in Cloudinary?

Tags: video, analytics, cloudinary

Looking to access video analytics for video uploads to Cloudinary.

For example, on this video:

https://assets.travel-media.co/video/upload/v1648753595/kensingtontours/whyilove_webinar_recordings/singapore-culture-cuisine-and-curiosity-webinar-march-2022.mp4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of all possible events here, there is also an easy integration with Google Analytics that sends all of those and they're reported in Google's interface: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/video_player_api_reference#events

Here is another blog that you can refer to: https://cloudinary.com/guides/marketing-videos/video-tracking-with-google-analytics-made-simple